# Mercurial and python 2.6

Tags: python, mercurial, centos

I try to install mercurial on a centos vps-server with "yum install mercurial" but it says it needs python2.4 in order to install it. I have python2.6 installed. Is there a way to get past this?

Comment: Have you tried installing Python 2.4?

Comment: No, I would prefer not to mess with python (too afraid i'll break something regarding yum-functionality). Should I try and install 2.4 anyway? Is there a yum-command for installing a specific version of python?

Comment: Did you remove python 2.4 from your system? On older(?) versions of CentoOS, Python 2.4 is the system python and `yum` won't work without it at all.

Comment: What version of python pops up when you run `python` from the shell?

Comment: I have never removed python 2.4 but I don't think it's ever been there

Answer (score 1):

You should not have messed with your system Python -- 
it is incrdible you can still login at all. Python 2.4 is ancient, but it is what is used in a lot of CentOS versions in the wild - what is installed by it's package management. Maybe you had installed a ",meta package" taht upgrades the system Python to 2.6, along with everything that depends on it (yum included).

Anyway, 2.4 would be sub-optimal to install mercurial. 
Since your system is a mess already, you can simply easy_install mercurial into your system Python instead of trying to use yum for it.

"sudo easy_install mercurial"  -- if you don't have easy_install, try "yum install setuptools" first. If this does not work, search on pipy.python.org for setuptools, install it manually - -and think seriously on rebuilding this machinne - you will have to do it soon.

Comment: okay, that's not good. I would much prefer not to reinstall the machine. What steps do I take to correct the system?